# Bash script to read two specific lines from text file and use parts of them as variable

Tags: bash, text-processing, scripting

So i got a text file which looks like this

```
# begin build properties
# autogenerated by buildinfo.sh
ro.build.id=LRX21T
ro.build.version.incremental=G900FXXU1BOK6
ro.build.version.sdk=21
ro.build.version.codename=REL
ro.build.version.all_codenames=REL
ro.build.version.release=5.0
ro.build.version.security_patch=2015-11-01
ro.build.version.base_os=
ro.build.date=Mon Nov 23 14:29:35 KST 2015
ro.build.date.utc=1448256575
ro.build.type=user
ro.build.user=dpi
ro.build.host=SWHD4408
ro.build.tags=release-keys
ro.product.model=SM-G900F
ro.product.brand=samsung
ro.product.name=kltexx
ro.product.device=klte
ro.product.board=MSM8974
# ro.product.cpu.abi and ro.product.cpu.abi2 are obsolete,
# use ro.product.cpu.abilist instead.
ro.product.cpu.abi=armeabi-v7a
ro.product.cpu.abi2=armeabi
ro.product.cpu.abilist=armeabi-v7a,armeabi
ro.product.cpu.abilist32=armeabi-v7a,armeabi
ro.product.cpu.abilist64=
ro.product.manufacturer=samsung
....
```

What i want are the lines

- ro.product.model=SM-G900F
- ro.build.version.incremental=G900FXXU1BOK6

but not complete, only what comes after `=` so `SM-G900F` and `G900FXXU1BOK6`.

I know this can be done some way, either with `awk` or `grep` but i don't know how exactly. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -n 's/^ro.product.model=//p;s/^ro.build.version.incremental=//p' file
```

or

```
sed -nr 's/^(ro.product.model|ro.build.version.incremental)=//p' file
```

Output:

```
G900FXXU1BOK6
SM-G900F
```

---

or with current GNU bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do
  [[ $line =~ ^(ro.product.model=) ]] && r="${line#*${BASH_REMATCH[1]}}"$'\n'"$r"
  [[ $line =~ ^(ro.build.version.incremental=) ]] && r="${line#*${BASH_REMATCH[1]}}"
done < file
echo "$r"
```

Output:

```
SM-G900F
G900FXXU1BOK6
```

Comment: I've updated the bash part.

Comment: Had to modify a bit to show like this `(Model: SM-G900F / Build: G900FXXU1BOK6)` but as i did not state this in my question it's clearly my fault. Nonetheless this works as expected, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Use `grep` to match the line and `cut` to select the part you want:

```
grep ro.product.model input.txt |cut -d= -f2
```

The `-d` option set `=` as separator and the `-f` option select the second field.

Comment: i like that you explained the `options` set. take an upvote (as soon as i got 15 rep)

Answer (score 0):

Use below command it will give you the result :

```
egrep 'ro.product.model|ro.build.version.incremental' a.txt | awk -F'=' '{print $2}'
```

egrep is as same as grep -e and is used here to search multiple expression as the same time. Awk is just doing the extracting the data after "="

G900FXXU1BOK6

SM-G900F

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F= '$1 ~ /^(ro.product.model|ro.build.version.incremental)$/ { print $2 }'
```

Using a field delimiter of `=`, print the second field only if the first field matches the regexp pattern `^(ro.product.model|ro.build.version.incremental)$`

Comment: probably should use `\.` (which matches only literal `.`) rather than plain `.` (which matches *any* character), but in this case, it makes no difference.  i.e. `^(ro\.product\.model|ro\.build\.version\.incremental)$`